# Extract a string that is located above and nearest to the matching pattern in a multiline output

Tags: shell, awk

Below is the HP `ssacli` command to see configured hardware RAID details:

```
ssacli ctrl slot=0 show config
```

and its output is as below:

```
HPE Smart Array P408i-a SR Gen10 in Slot 0 (Embedded)



   Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 1, OK



   Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 0, OK


   Port Name: 1I (Mixed)

   Port Name: 2I (Mixed)

   Array A (Solid State SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (447.10 GB, RAID 1, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS SSD, 480 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS SSD, 480 GB, OK)

   SEP (Vendor ID HPE, Model Smart Adapter) 379  (Port: Unknown)
```

I have to figure out the ***Array*** name in order to delete it by searching for the matching disk info which I get as input from the user. For example if the disk input is `1I:1:1`, then I have to search this string in the output of the above command. Since this disk is available and matching, I have to extract the Array name (here it is `A`) and once I get this Array parameter then I can go ahead delete this existing RAID configuration.

```
ssacli ctrl slot=0 show config | grep -B 4 '1I:1:1' | grep Array | awk '{print $2}'
```

The problem with the above command is,

1. value 4 in the `grep -B` cannot be always constant as the matching disk may come first, second or third or so on under an Array in the output.
2. there may be multiple RAID array configurations available in the output, so there may be Array `A`, `B`, `C` etc., I have to find and retrieve the nearest `Array` string that matches my input disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your requirement could be simply solved with a *single* usage of `awk`. You store the disk name as a variable to be passed and first store the array names as you go through the list of lines. Once you do a match of the actual disk name, you print the array you just stored. So pipe your command output to

```
| awk -v disk="1I:1:1" '/^[[:space:]]*Array/{ array=$2; } $0 ~ disk { print array; exit  }'
```

This answer *assumes* that the array names do not contain spaces or else it would be broken and would print the first part of the array name only.

Answer (score 2):

You can process the file from the end:

```
tac infile \
    | awk -v input='1I:1:1' '$0 ~ input {flag=1} flag && /Array/ {print $2; exit}'
```

This sets a flag when encountering a line matching the user input; after that, if a line matches `Array` and the flag is set, the second field is printed.